# Acces variable of subclass, using a pointer array of base class

Tags: c++, inheritance

I hope I formulated the title a bit correct.

I have this base class

```
class FunctionBlock
{
public:
    uint8_t    IN1 : 1 ;
    uint8_t    IN2 : 1 ;
    uint8_t    IN3 : 1 ;
    uint8_t      Q : 1 ;
    uint8_t  Q_NOT : 1 ;

    virtual void run() ;
} ;
```

And many subclasses like

```
class Or : public FunctionBlock  // there is also And, JK, SR, NOT etc..
{
public:
    Or()
    {
        IN1 = IN2 = IN3 = 0 ;
    }

    void run()
    {
        Q = IN1 | IN2 | IN3 ;
    }
} ;
```

And the one with the problem:

```
class AnalogOutput : public FunctionBlock
{
public:

    AnalogOutput( uint8_t _pin )
    {
        pin = _pin ;
    }

    void run()
    {
        if( analogIN2 != prevIn )
        {   prevIn  = analogIN2 ;                // if incoming change, update PWM level

            analogWrite( pin, analogIN2 ) ;
            // Serial.println( analogIN2 ) ; // DEBUG just testing if it... actually works
        }
    }

    uint8_t analogIN2 ;                // I need to be 8 bits instead of 1 bit

private:
    uint8_t pin ;
    uint8_t prevIn ;
} ;
```

The main program process the logic of all function blocks and it updates the links. The links used to exist of a connection from a Q to an IN1, IN2 or IN3. Using bit fields I can stuff these in one single byte.

Now I have added analog components, so a single bit for Q and IN does not suffice. To solve this problem, I added the public variable `analogIN2` as seen in the analogOutput class. Similarly I use a public variable `int analogQ`for an analog input.

For the links I make a destinction between digital and analog links.

Obivously I could change

```
uint8_t    IN1 : 1 ;
    uint8_t    IN2 : 1 ;
    uint8_t    IN3 : 1 ;
    uint8_t      Q : 1 ;
```

Into

```
    uint16_t    IN1 ; // instead of 1 byte, I would need 8 bytes
    uint16_t    IN2 ;
    uint16_t    IN3 ;
    uint16_t      Q ;
```

But this would increase memory consumption, so I keep this as a last resort

```
#include "functionBlocks.h"

static  AnalogInput b1 =  AnalogInput(1) ;
static AnalogOutput b2 = AnalogOutput(5) ;
static          And b3 =          And() ;
static           Or b4 =           Or() ;

FunctionBlock *block[] = {
    &b1 ,
    &b2 ,
    &b3 ,
    &b4 ,
} ;
const int nBlocks = 4 ;

void setup()
{
}

void loop()
{
/***************** UPDATE FUNCTION BLOCKS *****************/
    for( int i = 0 ; i < nBlocks ; i ++ ) block[i] -> run() ;

/***************** UPDATE LINKS *****************/
    block[1] -> analogIN2 = block[0] -> analogQ ;  // <-- analog link does not compile
    block[3] -> IN2 = block[2] -> Q ;              //     digital links work fine
    block[2] -> IN3 = block[3] -> Q ;
} ;
```

I marked the line which does not compile.

```
C:\Users\me\Documents\hobbyProjects\functionBloX\arduinoProgram\arduinoProgram.ino:26:17: error: 'class FunctionBlock' has no member named 'analogIN2'
     block[1] -> analogIN2 = block[0] -> analogQ ;
```

The reason is obvious, the base class does not know about `analogIn` and `analogQ`. Therefor the array 'block[]' does not have acces to the members.

My questions:
Can I let the `FunctionBlock *block[]` objects give acces to `analogQ` without increasing memory usage drastically. And if so, how can I do that?

The one thing I could think of was to add a 2nd baseclass but I do not know every last in and out of c++, hence this question.

Comment: Perhaps you should reconsider your design. Like for example to use different structures for analog and binary blocks. They can still inherit from a common `FunctionalBlock` structure, which doesn't contain any data only abstract function describing  behavior (if the behavior can be common for both digital and analog blocks).

Comment: Analog in/out/processing are fundamentally different things from digital logic blocks. Reconsider your class structure, you'll probably have a better time with two different hierarchies for those.

Comment: @Mat I get your point and I partially agree. But the real difference here, is just some bits. If I would let the Qs and INs to use 16 bits, there would not be a problem (besides wasting memory).

I am also thinking to make a comperator block. It would have 2 analog inputs but a single digital output.

But if I understand correctly, I can make one base class followed by 2 sub classes like 'analogBlocks' and 'digitalBlocks' and than create all the sub classes for the blocks?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude > (if the behavior can be common for both digital and analog blocks)
It kinda is the same in my application. The links work basically the same. A IN of one block gets the value of a Q of another block, whether 1 or 16 bits are used. `block[i]->IN = block[i]->Q.

Comment: The problem is that your are using a bit field for the digital thing, and a bit field is a very peculiar animal... My first thought was to use templates here, but I do not think that they will lead to a nice code.

Answer (score 0):

You could even go entirely without inheritance and polymorphism:

```
#include <tuple>

static auto blocks = std::make_tuple(AnalogInput(1), AnalogOutput(5), And(), Or());

void loop()
{
    // Using the tuple elements as arguments to a suitable function
    auto run_all = [](auto&... args) { (args.run(), ...); };
    std::apply(run_all, blocks);

    // Assuming that the digital and analog blocks now have members
    // of the same name
    auto& [b1, b2, b3, b4] = blocks;
    b2.IN2 = b1.Q;
    b4.IN2 = b3.Q;
    b3.IN3 = b4.Q;
}
```

Admittedly, the interface of tuples is not as nice as that of arrays or other containers, but they are an option.

If all blocks have the same basic data, you could parametrise that using a template:

```
#include <concepts>

template<std::integral T = uint8_t, unsigned N = 1>
struct BlockData
{
    T IN1   : N = 0;
    T IN2   : N = 0;
    T IN3   : N = 0;
    T Q     : N = 0;
    T Q_NOT : N = 0;
};
```

You can also use your current approach, but then the data would need to be encapsulated behind virtual get/set functions:

```
struct FunctionBlock {
    virtual ~FunctionBlock() = default;
    virtual void run() = 0;

    // Set channel 1 to the given value
    virtual void in1(uint8_t) = 0;
    // etc.
};
```